# In IIS how does one change the allowed postback duration so it doesn't timeout while debugging code behind?

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7

In IIS how does one change the allowed postback duration so it doesn't imeout while debugging code behind?
Perhaps this is in the web.config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try setting the `executionTimeout` attribute In web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="30000"/>
    ...
</system.web>
```

Comment: The [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx) article says "This time-out applies only if the debug attribute in the compilation element is False. If the debug attribute is True, to help avoiding application shut-down while you are debugging, do not set this time-out to a large value."